# getting Request failed with status code 404 with axios PUT

Tags: axios, http-status-code-404, vuejs3, put

I am currently developing a small exchange rate app with Vue 3 and facing a small issue with `axios`.

The `GET` request to the endpoint works like a charm, however the `PUT` doesn't.

This is my `axios` definition of the endpoint, which I simulate it with `json-server`.

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:3000";
axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
axios.defaults.headers.put["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```

The JSON response looks like this:

```
{
  "conversion": [
    {
      "base": "USD",
      "rates": {
        "EUR": 0.948434,
        "GBP": 0.795324,
        "USD": 1,
        "CNY": 6.6085
      }
    },
    {
      "base": "EUR",
      "rates": {
        "USD": 1.0543696,
        "GBP": 0.838565,
        "EUR": 1,
        "CNY": 6.967802
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The `GET` request to the endpoint looks like this:

```
async getRates() {
      await this.axios.get("/conversion/").then((result) => {
        this.conversion = result.data;
        this.conversionLoaded = true;
        this.getRatesForBase(this.selected);
      });
    },
```

However, the `PUT`request throws an 404 error.

```
editValues() {
      this.keys.forEach((key, index) => {
        this.editRates(key, this.values[index]);
      });
},

async editRates(key, value) {
      await this.axios
        .put("/conversion", {
          base: this.selected,
          rates: { [JSON.stringify(key)]: value },
        })
        .then((resp) => {
          console.log(resp.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

This is how the payloads looks like, driven from the loop:

```
{
  "base": "EUR",
  "rates": {
    "GBP": 0.838565
  }
}

{
  "base": "EUR",
  "rates": {
    "CNY": 6.967802
  }
}
```

I understand the meaning of the 404 error. Everything looks good to me, but I can't make it work. And I wonder what am I missing. Please help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont know if this could make a difference but in your GET request you use "/conversion/" and in your PUT request you use "/conversion".

Comment: tried both ways, however it's still not working.

Comment: Does your backend support PUT for this endpoint?

Comment: yes. I also can't send this request over Postman either.

Comment: Can you add the full error in the question?